# nested try catch Issues in c++

Tags: c++

i am having problem with nested try-catch block in c++,

it is not perfectly passing the values(pointer, maybe the scope is reason),getting null in outer try-catch block

```
try{
     try{
          string e
          ...
          throw e.c_str();
        }
     catch(const char *a){
          throw a;    // I had also tried taking 'a' into another string object and then throwed it but it didn't work
     }          
   }
catch(const char *a){
   cout<<a<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The scope is definitely a problem here. But I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 4):

When you throw exception in inner `try` block, `e` `string` gets destroyed in the *stack unwinding* process and pointer to its buffer no longer points to a valid memory location.

The general rule is: throw *by value*, catch *by reference*.

```
try
{
    try
    {
        string e
        ...
        throw e;
    }
    catch(string & a)
    {
        throw a;
    }
}
catch(string & a)
{
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Result: https://ideone.com/nY0FYM

Comment: `throw by value, catch by reference.` .... and use special classes for exception. Not fundamental types like int, nor pointer to anything. Consider deriving from std::exception or make your own hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a pointer to the internal buffer of a `std::string` local object. The object no longer exists by the time the catch block comes into scope. You should throw the string object, not its internal buffer.

Answer (score 0):

When an exception is thrown, all variables allocated on stack since enter to `try{}` block to the point of where exception happened are destroyed as part of a process called stack unwinding. Thus your pointer in a `catch()` points to already deallocated memory. You can avoid this by throwing by value, so copying value to the exception object being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The `string` goes out of scope, so the `char const *` is pointing wild. To fix this, you can throw a derivative of `std::exception` (which takes string as constructor argument), but catch a `std::exception &`. Then an exception object is created that contains that string, and everything is fine.